# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, undefined

I got this problem, which I just can't get to work.

```
<?php
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `news_vertical`";
            $sql2=mysql_query($sql) or die("Couldn't etablish connection with the server or username wasn't found in the database.");
            $count=mysql_num_rows($sql2);
            if($count>0)
            {
                while($row = $sql2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if($row["Pull-LR"] == 'Right')
                    {
                        echo '<hr class="featurette-divider"><div class="row featurette"><div class="col-md-7"><h2 class="featurette-heading">', $row["title"], '</h2><span class="text-muted">- Skrevet af: ', $row["userstamp"], '</span><p class="lead">', $row["text"], '</p></div><div class="col-md-5"><img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="500x500" src="', $row["picture_url"], '" data-holder-rendered="true"></div></div><div class="row featurette"><div class="col-md-2 pull-left"><p>Skrevet den: ', $row["timestamp"], '</p></div></div>';
                    }
                    else if($row["Pull-LR"] == 'Left')
                    {
                        echo '<hr class="featurette-divider"><div class="row featurette"><div class="col-md-5"><img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="500x500" src="', $row["picture_url"], '" data-holder-rendered="true"></div><div class="col-md-7"><h2 class="featurette-heading">', $row["title"], '</h2><span class="text-muted">- Skrevet af: ', $row["userstamp"], '</span><p class="lead">', $row["text"], '</p></div></div><div class="row featurette"><div class="col-md-2 pull-right"><p>Skrevet den: ', $row["timestamp"], '</p></div></div>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                die("Could't find 'news_vertical' database.");
            }
        ?>
```

I'm sure the tables are correct, it's just, I can't get it to list the information.

Comment: Try replacing "$result" with "$sql2"

Comment: Okay, now it's only this error left: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on resource in '\index.php' on line 7"

Comment: The whole `mysql_*` family of functions is DEPRECATED and it's dangerous and discouraged to use them in new code. Look at `mysqli`. As for the error, I'd try `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)`, but I'm not really sure, I haven't used this API in years

Comment: `mysql` (not `mysqli`) doesn't even have OO style api

Comment: Read the manual -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Aside: `$sql2` is probably not an appropriate variable name for a query result. SQL is a string, but a query result is a **resource**. I tend to use `$result` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problem, you need to use the MySQL procedural function syntax:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    // Run your code
}
```

However, you shouldn't be using MySQL. Have a look at MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Okay that worked. Thanks! I'll try change everything from MySQL to MySQLi. :)